# How to pass BasicDBList of $OR criteria to QueryBuilder?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

My app is dynamically generating a mongo query via a QueryBuilder.  I'm trying to make it so that the passed text can be compared against several fields in my collection. I need to iterate through data in order to know what to add to the $OR ( 'text_to_compare' vs title field, 'text_to_compare vs body field), so I've been trying to store each section of the $OR clause in a BasicDBList as follows:

```js
BasicDBObject orsDBObject = new BasicDBObject();

BasicDBList orsList = new BasicDBList();

for( String dbFieldNameInstance: listDBFieldName ){

  QueryBuilder innerQB = new QueryBuilder();

  innerQB.put(dbFieldNameInstance).is(obj.getValue()); //using this inner QueryBuilder to assist in creating the document

  orsList.add(innerQB.get());

}

orsDBObject.putAll(orsList); //put each of the BasicDBList items into a BasicDBObject

qb.or(orsDBObject); //finally, add the entire $OR clause to my bigger querybuilder

System.out.println("qb: " + qb.get());
```

It seems like I might be jumping through more conversions than are necessary.  It isn't working either.  The output from the above ends up looking like this:

> qb: { "$or" : [ { "0" : { "primary_industries_names" : "electrical"} , "1" : { "primary_industries_aliases" : "electrical"} , "2" : { "secondary_industries_names" : "electrical"} , "3" : { "secondary_industries_aliases" : "electrical"} , "4" : { "product_experience_names" : "electrical"} , "5" : { "product_experience_aliases" : "electrical"}}]}

For the most part it looks right to me, however I don't think the "0": should be appearing in there.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You kind of have that the wrong way around. Not re-writing your code, but you *should* get the idea:

```java
    // Before the loop
    QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();

    // And loop things like this
    for ( ) {
        qb.or(new BasicDBObject("this","that"));
    }

    // After loop

    System.out.println(qb.get());
```

If you are trying to nest several conditions then you seem to be missing the `$and` operator. Consider the following:

```java
    QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();

    for (int x=0; x<2;x++) {
        qb.or(new BasicDBObject("this","that"));
    }

    QueryBuilder qb2 = new QueryBuilder();

    qb2.and(qb.get());

    QueryBuilder qb3 = new QueryBuilder();
    for (int x=0; x<2;x++) {
        qb3.or(new BasicDBObject("something", "else"));
    }
    qb2.and(qb3.get());
    System.out.println(qb2.get());
```

Comment: Thanks, Neil.  This is getting me very close.  Now the qb object contains a valid $or.  But I need to take that or condition and add it to a different querybuilder object that contains several queries.  (a main querybuilder is passed into my method.  it may already contain some "or"s or "put"s and now I need to append this or condition to it.)  When I try qb_outer.or(qb), I end up with a nested or condition.  Is there a way I can do something like qb_outer.or(qb.getOrConditions()) ? - that doesn't exist I know.

Comment: @Erich See if the additional information helps you.

Comment: @Erich glad to be of help. Your **acceptance** of the answer would be appreciated :)